# jquery ui - how to drop image into a modal

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have been trying hard to get this to work. I have a modal which I call when draggable - drag function is called. I want to drop the element into this modal which was called. I cannot seem to focus the draggable element into the modal. Can someone help me with this problem. Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Executed once all the page elements are loaded
     //setup new person dialog
        $('#newPerson').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                height: '400px',
                width: '600px',
                title: "Drag to FB, Twitter",
                open: function(type, data) {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                }
            });  

 // The hover method takes a mouseover and a mouseout function:
 $(".tut").hover(
```

function(){

$(this).find('.drag-label').stop().animate({marginTop:'-50px'},'fast');
  },

function(){

$(this).find('.drag-label').stop().animate({marginTop:'0'},'fast');
  }

);

$(".tut-img").draggable(
            {
                hoverClass: "dropHover",
                helper: "clone", 
                opacity: "0.5", 
                handle: ".tut-img",    // makes toolbar the dragable part
                drag: function(ev, ui) {
                   $('#newPerson').dialog("open");
                },
                stop: function(ev, ui) {
                   $('#newPerson').dialog("close");
                }
            }
         );
        $(".newPersonDrop").droppable(
        {
            accept: ".tut-img",
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
                var droppedItem = ui.draggable.clone().addClass("droppedItemStyle");
                $(this).append(droppedItem);
                alert('I get called');
            }
        }
        );

});

Answer (score 0):

First cache your dialog

```
var dialog=$('#newPerson').dialog({
  //dialog options
});
```

In your droppable function

```
$('.newPersonDrop').droppable({
  //droppable options
  drop: function(event, ui){
    dialog.empty().append($(ui.draggable).clone());
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi,
  I tried what you suggested. It is acting quite strange. When i drag the image outside of the modal bounds all the way to the top and then come into the modal - i can drop it into the modal. Otherwise when i drag the image straight to the modal, it does not work! Any ideas as to why this might be happening?